# How would I fill my TextFields after I select an item from JList

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jlist, jmenu

i'm having some trouble with a homework problem, and still trying to wrap my head around GUI logically. I have created all my text fields (contactType, name, address, city, state, etc...) and have created an actionListener to populate my JList with names when I click open from the JMenu.  I'm running into trouble filling in the appropriate text fields when I select the name from the list. I tried to just print out to console to see if it would print out at least the name, but that's not even working. Any help would be great, thanks.

Here's some of my code so far:

```
public class AddressBookGUI extends JFrame
{   

    private final int WIDTH = 450;
    private final int HEIGHT = 300;

    private JLabel currentlySelected;
    private JTextField contactTypeTextField;
    private JTextField nameTextField;   
    private JTextField streetAddressTextField;   
    private JTextField cityTextField;
    private JTextField stateTextField;
    private JTextField zipTextField;
    private JTextField phoneTextField; 
    private JTextField emailTextField;
    private JTextField photoTextField;
    private JList nameList ;   
    private DefaultListModel model;
    private JTextArea statusTextArea;   
    private AddressBook addressBook; 
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton editButton;
    private JButton sortByZipButton;
    private JMenuItem addItem;
    private JMenuItem openItem;
    private JMenuItem saveItem;
    private JMenuItem exitItem;
    private JMenuItem editContactItem;
    private JMenuItem aboutItem;
    private JMenuItem deleteItem;
    private JComboBox<String> jComboStates;
    private JComboBox <Enum> jComboContactType;

    private String [] readStates()
    {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream ("States.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (fStream));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = buffer.readLine()) != null)
            {   
                String line = buffer.readLine();
                String [] state = line.split ("\n");
                array.add(strLine);
            }
            buffer.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return array.toArray(new String[array.size()]);         
    }

    private  ArrayList<String> readContacts()
    {
        File cFile = new File ("Contacts.txt");
        BufferedReader buffer = null;
        ArrayList <String> contact = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            buffer = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (cFile));
            String text;
            String sep;
            while ((sep = buffer.readLine()) != null)
            {   
                String [] name = sep.split (",");
                text = name[1];
                contact.add(text);  
            }   
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.print ("error");
        }
        catch (IOException k)
        {
            System.out.print ("error);
        }
        return contact;
    }

    {

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu ("File");
        openItem = new JMenuItem ("Open...");
        fileMenu.add (openItem);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        saveItem = new JMenuItem ("Save...");
        fileMenu.add (saveItem);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        exitItem = new JMenuItem ("Exit");
        fileMenu.add (exitItem);
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu ("Edit");
        editContactItem = new JMenuItem ("Edit Contact");
        editMenu.add (editContactItem);
        addItem = new JMenuItem ("Add Contact");
        editMenu.add (addItem);
        deleteItem = new JMenuItem ("Delete Contact");
        editMenu.add (deleteItem);
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu ("Help");
        aboutItem = new JMenuItem ("About");
        helpMenu.add(aboutItem);
        menuBar.add (fileMenu);
        menuBar.add (editMenu);
        menuBar.add (helpMenu);
        setJMenuBar (menuBar);

        //code that creates new text fields for all attributes

        //code that sets textfields to uneditable

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel()

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        leftPanel.add (currentlySelected, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        leftPanel.add (new JScrollPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel (new BorderLayout());
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout (9,1);
        JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel (layout);
        JPanel valuesPanel = new JPanel (layout);

       // code that added lables and values to panel

        infoPanel.add (labelsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        infoPanel.add (valuesPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerPanel.add (infoPanel);

        setLayout (new BorderLayout());
        add (topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add (leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add (centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        addressBook = new AddressBook();  
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible (true);

        openItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                readContacts();
                for (String name :readContacts())
                {
                    model.addElement(name);
                }

                nameList = new JList (model);
                add(nameList);
                nameList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
                nameList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                nameList.setFixedCellHeight (20);
                nameList.setFixedCellWidth (130);

                JPanel left = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                left.add (new JScrollPane(nameList), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                add (left, BorderLayout.WEST);
                nameList.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
            }
        });

        editContactItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                 nameTextField.setEditable (true);
                 streetAddressTextField.setEditable (true);
                 cityTextField.setEditable (true);
                 jComboStates.setEditable (true);
                 zipTextField.setEditable (true);
                 phoneTextField.setEditable (true);
                 emailTextField.setEditable (true);
                 photoTextField.setEditable (true);
            }       
        });

        saveItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                addressBook.Save ( );
            }
        });

       nameList = new JList ();
        nameList.addListSelectionListener (new ListSelectionListener()
        {

            public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting ( ) == false)
                {   
                    List <String> string = nameList.getSelectedValuesList();
                    System.out.print (string);
                }
            }

        });

        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    int index = nameList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                    System.out.println("Double clicked on Item " + index);
                 }
            }
        };
        nameList.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    }
```

I tried cut out some of the tedious code to keep it short.  If I could get a skeleton or a nudge in the right direction, it would be a great help.

So i've changed it up a bit, once I select open, it populates the JList with the names, then when I double click on a name it only fills the nameTextField, addressTextField, and cityTextField all with the name of the contact I selected

ex) Name: Zoidberg, Address: Zoidberg, City: Zoidberg

here's my code:

```js
        openItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
        {
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
         {
          readContacts();
                for (String name :readContacts())
                {
                 model.addElement(name);
                }
               
                nameList = new JList (model);
                add(nameList);
                nameList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
                nameList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                nameList.setFixedCellHeight (20);
                nameList.setFixedCellWidth (130);
                
                JPanel left = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                left.add (new JScrollPane(nameList), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                add (left, BorderLayout.WEST);
                
                nameList.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
             
                MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                            int index = nameList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                            if (nameList.getModel().getElementAt(index) != null && nameList.getModel().getElementAt(index) instanceof String)
                            {
                             
                             nameTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             streetAddressTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             cityTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             stateTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             zipTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             phoneTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             emailTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             photoTextField.setText((String) nameList.getModel().getElementAt (index));
                             
                            }
                         }
                    }
                };
                nameList.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/649433/GUI/java/fill-text-fields-selection-JList#2996371

Answer (score 3):

```
nameList = new JList (model);
```

You add data to the JList with the above code.

But then later you do:

```
   nameList = new JList ();
    nameList.addListSelectionListener (new ListSelectionListener()
    {

        public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting ( ) == false)
            {   
                List <String> string = nameList.getSelectedValuesList();
                System.out.print (string);
            }
        }

    });
```

Which creates an empty List and adds a ListSelectionListener to this list. This serves no purpose since the JList is empty and is not visible on the GUI anyway.

Add the ListSelectListener to the JList when you create the JList and add data to it:

```
nameList = new JList (model);
nameList.addListSelectionListener(...);
```

Comment: I knew it was wrong to declare a new JList for nameList, but I would get NullPointerException otherwise. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

I second all that Rob Camick writes. Also, you're only adding name Strings to your list and not complete Address objects, and so key information is lost. To gain it, make your JList a list of Address objects, give it a custom cell renderer that shows only the name, but this will allow your selected object to have all the data that you need.

Comment: Would this replace the JList, or is something completely different?

Comment: @ChelseaH: no, you would use the same JList but make it a `JList<Address>` (assuming that you've got an Address class or something similar), not a `JList<String>`. Search the Java Swing tutorials on how to use JLists and it will help you create a custom cell renderer that will display the name String in the JList.

Comment: Yes, create the custom Address object, it will make is easy to populate the text fields once you select the name from the list. (+1).

Comment: Since I've figured out the JList problem already, I'll move onto reading about this cell renderer.  Small steps.